# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-YY Qx in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot data by quarter then display in ggplot. Dates in `dataset` are of the format YYYY-MM-DD, and I want the ggplot x-axis to display the financial year like YYYY-YY Qx. The financial year starts July 1.

Data is in long format. This is where I've got to:

```
      Data set named: TOX

TREE_ID    PM_Date                        variable value
1: 2013000584 2013-04-02               elm           0
2: 2013000498 2013-06-11               elm           1
3: 2013000123 2013-09-03               maple         0
4: 2013000642 2014-02-15               maple         0
5: 2013000778 2016-07-08               maple         1

PM_Dateq <- as.yearqtr(TOX$PM_Date, format)

Tox_longer_yr <- TOX [,list(value=sum(value)), by=list(PM_Dateq, variable)]

ggplot(Tox_longer_yr, aes(x = PM_Dateq, y = value, colour = variable)) 
+ geom_line()
```

The X-axis currently displaying as:

```
2015, 2016, 2017...etc
```

(Though it is grouped into quarters in ggplot correctly.)

I want the x-axis to look like:

```
2015-16 Q3, 2015-16 Q4, 2016-17 Q1, 2016-17 Q2...etc
```

So an event happening on 2016-02-13 would be grouped into "2015-16 Q3".

Comment: Please edit your post to include reproducible sample data and your code attempt.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368157/transforming-calendar-quarter-to-financial-quarter).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
library(lubridate)
df %>%
    mutate(
        PM_Date = as.Date(PM_Date),
        Qtr = sprintf("%s-%s Q%i",
            year(PM_Date),
            year(PM_Date %m+% years(1)),
            cut(
                month(tmp$PM_Date),
                breaks = c(0, 3, 6, 9, 12),
                labels = c("Q3", "Q4", "Q1", "Q2")))) %>%
    group_by(Qtr, variable) %>%
    summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Qtr, y = value, colour = variable, group = variable)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Explanation: We construct a new `Qtr` variable in the form `YYYY-YYYY QX` by extracting the year from `PM_Date`, and binning the months into 3 month bins starting from 1 July using `cut`. We use `lubridate` for easy extraction of the year and "date arithmetic" (for the second `YYYY` we add one year to the current year).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "TREE_ID    PM_Date                        variable value
2013000584 2013-04-02               elm           0
2013000498 2013-06-11               elm           1
2013000123 2013-09-03               maple         0
2013000642 2014-02-15               maple         0
2013000778 2016-07-08               maple         1", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It runs, however the data is not being grouped correctly. For example an event on 2016-11-03 is being put into 2016-2017 Q4 when it should go into 2016-2017 Q2. Is it also possible to make the date say 2016-17 - i.e. without having the '20' a second time?

Comment: @epiR I can't confirm;  `"2016-11-03"` becomes `"2016-2017 Q2"`. Can you edit your question to update your sample data?